# .Net Socket Programming: File Descriptor

Tags: c#, sockets

I am doing some socket programming in C#. I would like to know how to get the file object associated with a socket connection like we have it in python by using socket.makefile(). I have read the msdn doc but I have not found something that could help in achieving that.

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: I guess you are looking for Streams. Can be this, perhaps? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Try an example and come back with some code if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, .NET hides low-level file operation in the abstract `System.IO.Stream` class.

So, right .NET-way to work with file operations is to use one of concrete descendants of `Stream`, f.e. `NetworkStream`.